Inverse Fast Fourier Transform from One-Sided Fourier Amplitude Spectra at Matlab
I am writing down a code that first apply Butterworth (low pass filter) to a earthquake time history and then create the one sided fourier amplitude of the filtered motion and multiply it with a transfer function to obtain the modified one sided fourier spectra and in the last step inverse fast fourier transform is applied to obtain acceleration time history of the modified motion.
I wrote a complete code, but in the ifft step, it doesn't work, i think it's because of that i am trying gto make ifft from one-sided amplitude spectra in a wrong way. Could you please help me about the last part ?
acci=load('Gilroy.txt');


% Butterworth filtresi parametreleri
cutoff_freq = 25; % Kesim frekansı (Hz)
filter_order = 4; % Filtre derecesi

% Butterworth filtresi tasarımı
[b, a] = butter(filter_order, cutoff_freq / (200 / 2), 'low');

% Filtreyi ivme kaydına uygulayın
acc = filtfilt(b, a, acci);



% Earthquake Data Process

dt = 0.005; % Zaman adımı
g = 9.81; % Yerçekimi ivmesi (m/s^2)

t = 0.0:dt:dt*(length(acc)-1);
% Hız ve yer değiştirme hesaplama
vel = cumsum(acc) * dt * g;
dis = cumsum(vel) * dt;
% Fourier Transform
Ts = dt; 
Fs = 1 / Ts;
ACC = fft(acc, 2^nextpow2(numel(acc)));
N = numel(acc); 
f = (0:(N-1)) / N * Fs;
m_ACC = abs(ACC) / N;
m_ACC = m_ACC(1:N/2+1);
m_ACC(2:end-1) = 2 * m_ACC(2:end-1); % Tek taraflı spektrum
f = f(1:N/2+1); % Sadece pozitif frekanslar için eksen

% Zemin Parametreleri (Sert kaya üzerinde uniform, sönümsüz zemin)
h = 3.05; % Kalınlık (m)
Vs = 320; % Vs30 (m/s)
k = h / Vs;
% Amplifikasyon Fonksiyonu
y = 1 ./ abs(cos(k * 2 * pi * f)); % Amplifikasyon Fonksiyonu
% Amplifikasyon Fonksiyonu ile çarpma
y = y';
N_FAS = y .* m_ACC;



% Ters Fourier dönüşümü (tek taraflı spektrumdan dönüşüm)
reconstructed_acc = ifft(N_FAS, 'symmetric'); % 'symmetric' seçeneği simetri sağlar
reconstructed_acc= reconstructed_acc*length(reconstructed_acc);

% Hız ve yer değiştirme hesaplama
reconstructed_vel = cumsum(reconstructed_acc) * dt * g;
reconstructed_dis = cumsum(reconstructed_vel) * dt;
% Zaman eksenini yeniden oluşturma
t_reconstructed = 2*(0:length(reconstructed_acc)-1) * dt;
% Sonuçları tek bir plot altında toplama (3x3 layout, transposed)
figure;
subplot(3,3,1), plot(t, acc, '-b');
xlabel('Time (sec)'), ylabel('Original Ground Acceleration (g)');
title('Original Ground Acceleration');
grid on;
subplot(3,3,4), plot(t, vel, '-b');
xlabel('Time (sec)'), ylabel('Velocity (m/sec)');
title('Velocity');
grid on;
subplot(3,3,7), plot(t, dis, '-b');
xlabel('Time (sec)'), ylabel('Displacement (m)');
title('Displacement');
grid on;
subplot(3,3,2), plot(f, m_ACC, '-b');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Original Fourier Amplitude (g-s)');
title('Original Fourier Amplitude (g-s)');
xlim([0 25]);
grid on;
subplot(3,3,5), plot(f, y, '-b');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Amplification Function');
title('Amplification Function');
xlim([0 25]);
grid on;
subplot(3,3,8), plot(f, N_FAS, '-b');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Modified Fourier Amplitude (g-s)');
title('Modified Fourier Amplitude (g-s)');
xlim([0 25]);
grid on;
subplot(3,3,3), plot(t_reconstructed, reconstructed_acc, '-b');
xlabel('Time (sec)'), ylabel('Reconstructed Ground Acceleration (g)');
title('Reconstructed Ground Acceleration');
grid on;
subplot(3,3,6), plot(t_reconstructed, reconstructed_vel, '-b');
xlabel('Time (sec)'), ylabel('Reconstructed Velocity (m/sec)');
title('Reconstructed Velocity');
grid on;
subplot(3,3,9), plot(t_reconstructed, reconstructed_dis, '-b');
xlabel('Time (sec)'), ylabel('Reconstructed Displacement (m)');
title('Reconstructed Displacement');
grid on;
% Plotları düzenleme
sgtitle('Earthquake Data Analysis');








Have you checked the help of ifft (see ifft), there is a paragraph how to convert the single-sided spectrum into a two sided spectrum.
